# Latest update has jumpy scrolling

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Stack Exchange's latest update, **1.0.49**, has glitchy, jumpy scrolling while viewing a question.
 It appears to be a jump-to because it returns to the end of a question/ answer.

Android 4.1.2
LG L39C (Optimus Dynamic II)
3.8" 320x480 screen
Stack Exchange 1.0.49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next update!

This was a really fun bug. At first I assumed it had to do something with the pull-to-refresh library being over eager on touch events, but it ended up being much simpler: Since some of the posts in the list had selectable elements (pictures, code blocks, etc) the ListView was assuming all children themselves were selectable too. So what happened was you tapped on an image to open it in the new window, but ended up also "selecting" the list item which caused it to scroll to the top.

Comment: That will do that... Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Looking great; just received the update! I have some more comments about the lightbox view that I will make a separate post for, but is that what you call it - the lightbox view?

Comment: @ADTC Lightbox is a good term for it, let's go with that :)

Comment: @Kasra the pull to refresh still jumps from question to answer then back to question.

Comment: Also does the app support suggested edits yet? I just get an error that "Account is not allowed to suggest edits" (which is wrong because I then did it via the mobile site). I also couldn't see the edits in the app after-the-fact while the review is pending (when the website says it will only be visible to me).

Comment: @ADTC looking into PTR issue. The app doesn't have suggested edits yet, since the API doesn't have them.

Comment: Well it is mostly fixed now, but I still see the issue in clicking comment

Answer (score 1):

Having this on SGS3 I9305 as well. You can consistently reproduce this by swiping left on any comment (when there is room to scroll up). But otherwise it just jumps around randomly.

You can also reproduce  this by swiping left and right on code blocks in a question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25957634/1134080). It's extremely unsightly when it does that. The app is almost unusable!

I think it's also related to the *pull to refresh* feature. Even though it's exactly how Gmail does it, I actually dislike it. I would prefer if the actual question did not get really pulled down (just have the blue bar on top fill up or empty itself as I move my finger up and down) OR if the question remains pinned to my finger (giving me a sense of control) only going up when I release it by lifting my finger.

Comment: Ya same, and with the pull to refresh, I like the old way where it says "Pull down to refresh" instead of a faint blue indicator.

Comment: +1 I'm _not_ getting weird and jumpy scrolling when I swipe a comment, but I _am_ getting it when I tap to open a code block. Earlier today, when tapping to open images in an answer ([this one](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/7884/5573)), the app would jump to the top of the answer sometimes. Both have that pop-up frame in common. This is really weird!

Comment: @EasyasPi Sadly the current pull-to-refresh is the new official Android way and the only way that's supported in new ListViews :(

Comment: I've noticed the tapping-code-block issue too, looking into it.

Comment: @Kasra Rahjerdi Could you maybe change the color to something brighter, like #33b5e5?

Comment: @EasyasPi I'm definitely a fan of changing the color to make it more obvious, playing around with different  colors right now.

Comment: I don't see the mixed colors in the refresh indicator. I think the current blue and the action bar's blue would be nice. Or how about the action bar blue and the upvote orange?

Comment: @Kasra I love the "pull to refresh" version used in the questions list (search results) of a site. That's way better than the "official Android way" used in individual questions, as it feels more natural and fluid. Not to mention it's a proper indicator and uses a better color. I hope you will consider copying that same mechanism to the question detail view (not the other way around, please!). Not everything has to be by the book :)

Comment: @ADTC Me too :( Sadly it flat out doesn't work with `RecyclerView`, the new list UI view in Android. Hopefully when Android L actually comes out they'll release the source code for `RecyclerView` and I can make it work with our other pull-to-refresh library.

Answer (score 1):

This may be partially related to the pop-up pane from code blocks and images. (Or at least, that's one circumstance in which scrolling goes loopy.)

Earlier today when tapping images in [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/7884/5573) the app would sometimes scroll to the top of that answer.

In [the question ADTC linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25957634/1134080), tapping a code block often leads to the question behind scrolling erratically once or twice.

This is in Android app v1.0.49 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Comment: Very often the behavior is erratically scrolling to the top of the question or the top of the answers, like there are anchors there and someone clicked a link to the ⚓.